# scala for comprehension with if statement results in compilation error that isn't understood

Tags: scala, syntax-error

getting an error when trying to apply a statement after an "if" in the for-yield. not clear why, I've seen similar examples elsewhere

```
value map is not a member of Long
      c <- f3
```

when trying to compile this code

```
def f1() : Try[A]
def f2() : Try[B]
def f3() : Long

val result = for {
              a <- f1
              b <- f2
              if b.status == successcode
              c <- f3 // apply once a and b succeeded, returns a Long , unused result , tried without c<- and directly just f3 but similar syntax error
            } yield a
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"throws"_ here? What is the type of `f1`, `f2` & `f3`. Finally, does the code fails to compile on a **real** compiler or it is just a Intellij complaining.

Comment: I'll update the code

Comment: [this _(basic)_ documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) should be enough to understand why your code doesn't compiles. You can fix it by doing `c = f3` instead of `c <- f3` or just `} yield f3` instead of `} yield c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<-` syntax is used to `map` over a collection of some sort, but `f3` does not return a collection. `f3` just returns a value so use `=` to assign this value to a result:

```
val result = for {
          a <- f1
          b <- f2
          if b.status == successcode
          c = f3
        } yield a
```

Comment: thank you sir. of course no documentation on that. (also tried without any sort of assignment as "c" is unused and that didn't work either....

Comment: @AvnerBarr; Since `c` is unused, it can be replaced with `_`, which might be a little clearer.